# android make imageview background frame src not stretch to available size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to make the background of the imageview be like frame around src while keeping the imageview width and height to match_parent

the problem is that the background stretch to the imageview's all available space as in the attached screenshot

help would be appreciated :D

the layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/header"
    android:src="@drawable/albumart_mp_unknown" />
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: set scale type fitxy for imageview.

Comment: i want to keep aspect ratio